# Proving the inequality $\|A\|_2 ^2 \le \|A\|_1 \|A\|_\infty$

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Consider $m\times n$ matrix $A$. I need to show that the following ineqaulity is satisified:

$$\|A\|_2^2 \le \|A\|_1 \|A\|_\infty$$

In all of my attempts I only managed to show that $\|A\|_2 ^2 \le \sqrt n\|A\|_1 \|A\|_\infty$ or similar inequalities, and I could not get rid of the $\sqrt n$. Can someone please give some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\|A\|_2^2=\lambda_{\max}(A^*A)\leq\|A^*A\|_\infty\leq\|A^*\|_\infty\|A\|_\infty=\|A\|_1\|A\|_\infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A=(x_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$,$$\|A\|_2^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^n{x_{ij}}^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^n|x_{ij}|^2\leqslant\sum_{i,j=1}^n|x_{ij}|\|A\|_\infty=\|A\|_\infty\|A\|_1.$$

Comment: But $||A||_1=\text {max} _{j=1,\dots ,n} \sum _{i=1} ^m |x_{ij}|$ and not the sum of the absolute values of the matrix elements. Am I right?

Comment: @MasterJ The usual definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$ is this this: on e fixes a basis and if the coordinates of $v$ on that basis are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, then $\|v\|_1=\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|$.

Comment: But this is the definition of vector 1-norm, and not the induced matrix 1-norm. I though that they are not the same.

Comment: @MasterJ And what made you think that $\|A\|_1$, when $A$ is a matrix, is what you say it is?

Comment: Why would these two definitions agree? Also, the first equality in the answer is the definition of the Frobenius matrix norm, and the induced matrix 2-norm. - which are not the same from what I know.

Comment: @MasterJ I never claimed that hey agree.